# How to decrease the height of a rectangle, from the top?

Tags: python, pygame

I am implementing a feature in my game where my character ducks. Therefore I would like to decrease the height of the player rect.

I have attempted to do this both with `rect.inflate(0,y)` and `rect.h = new_height`.
However the problem that I am running into is that these methods decrease the rect height from the bottom. How do I decrease the height from the top?

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.ducking = False

        self.image = pygame.image.load('Player/Player0.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
    
    def duck(self):
        if self.ducking: # This bool becomes True in another method
            self.image = pygame.image.load('Player/Player_duck.png')).convert_alpha()
            
            # Decrease rect height
            self.rect.h = new_height
```

Comment: Please share relevant code so we can replicate in our own machines and help guide.

Comment: How about decreasing the height and moving up by the difference at the same time?

Comment: Apart from your question: you should not _load_ an image inside a function that is part of game loop. The image should be loaded to an in-memory place (a variable, dictionary, whatever) before starting your scene (for simple games, as part of the setup, before entering the loop). What you are doing will work, but loading an image have all sorts of overheads that should not go between frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the rectangle top along with the height - and calculate how much the top have to be moved, using the difference in height for that.

When programing, there won't be a call or attribute for *everything* you want to do, and thinking of and creating the strategies to get to your needed results is part of the deal:

```
# on game toplevel, or inside a proper setup/init function:
ducked_image = pygame.image.load('Player/Player_duck.png')).convert_alpha()

...

class Player(...):

    ...

    def duck(self):
        if self.ducking: # This bool becomes True in another method
            self.image = ducked_image
            
            new_height = ducked_image.get_rect().h
            self.rect.top += self.rect.h - new_height
            self.rect.h = new_height
```